# Kак исправить предложения

Tags: грамотная-речь

Помогите исправить предложения:

> Так через его военную форму я начал представлять отца. Как в зеркале, форма отразилась в детской памяти-это отец!

Смысл таков: мальчику было 3 года, когда с войны вернулся его отец, ребенок не понимает, кто перед ним.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно изменить предложения, чтобы звучало грамотно.

Answer (score 1):

> Помогите исправить предложения: Так через его военную форму я начал
>   представлять отца. Как в зеркале, форма отразилась в детской памяти -
>   это отец!

А по-моему, ничего не стоит исправлять. Можно только испортить.

Comment: А запятые правильно расставлены?По-моему, после памяти напрашивается запятая.

Comment: Я бы оставил тире. См.: **§ 130.** В бессоюзном сложном предложении ставится **тире**… если вторая часть предложения начинается словами так, **это**, только, такой… (http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135 )

Comment: Хотя, если поставить запятую и тире, неправильным это  тоже не будет. См. примечание 1 к  § 130.